# Making a pandas data frame from an 'ill formatted' csv

Tags: pandas, dataframe, ipython

I am brand new to pandas dataframes, but they look super great! I have been trying different ways to read in a csv that looks like this:

```
$ Some Header of the file that we dont care about
  intdev(1,1)=   3.14159,   2.65358,   9.79323,   8.462643,
     3.83279,    3.14159,   2.65358,   9.79323,   8.462643,    3.83279,
  tindev(1,1)=   3.14159,   2.65358,   9.79323,   8.462643,
     3.83279,    3.14159,   2.65358,   9.79323,   8.462643,    3.83279,

$end
```

In a perfect world, Id like this to come out in columns (?, maybe wrong word): 'int', 'tin', '1', as the (1,1) denotes an iteration. The fact that the lines are uneven lengths has me tripped up.

Can I trouble the community for help?

Comment: The issue here is that your file isn't really a CSV. You will need to write something that parses the sections of your file properly and then constructs the relevant rows.